# What is the meaning of "match for" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I am translating error messages for a company (unfortunately I cannot reveal too much context here).

The message is "This optin does not match for this user". It it not clear to me 1) whether "optin" means "opt-in", or if it's a misspelling of "option", and 2) whether the phrase "match for" can be replaced with the word "match", or whether the meaning here is "the user has not selected this option"/"the user has not opted-in yet". The Google search results for "this optin", "optin does not match", etc. seem to be pretty divided on whether "optin" means "opt-in", or if it's simply a misspelling of "option", too.

Comment: What's the context? We have even less to go on to determine what *optin* should mean.

Comment: This sounds like a question for technical support at your company. Certainly "optin" could just as easily mean "opt-in" as being a misspelling of "option" and there is no way this can be determined externally.

Comment: These are separate error messages with not much connection between them, although the next message also includes the word "optin" ("This optin does not exist"), which makes me lean towards it being a misspelling of "option".

Comment: Whichever it is, the sentence is very poor. What would "match for this user" mean? I assume the English was written by non-native speakers? (Or engineers, which is almost the same thing :) )

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as someone who has done a little software development in the past,  I think the original message is trying to be a little coy with how much information it is giving away about the user in question, whilst also denying the action.

It appears they are using software-speak for “the option you are trying to use isn’t in the list of options available to this user”: i.e. the database has come back with ‘no match’ for the search query and the software writer just passed that message on.

The point is that the option in question (and indeed, the user) may or may not exist and, for security reasons, the software isn’t going to tell you.

Comment: If this guess is right (and it seems reasonable) then this would be an example of what one linguist has called "nerdview", where the message is written in terms of the underlying implementation instead of the user experience. So the OP needs to do some serious rewriting, rather than just translating.